# Input file field not posted in symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, file-upload, doctrine

I have form like this:

```
class EntityType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category'     , new CategoryType($this->em))
            ->add('entityTitle'   , 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Title',
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Title')
            ))
            ->add('entityDescription'  , 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Description',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Description')
            ))
            ->add('entityStarttime', 'text', array(
                'label'         => 'Start Time',
                'required'      => false
            ))
            ->add('entityEndtime', 'text', array(
                'label'         => 'End Time',
                'required'      => false
            ))
            ->add('entityInstantsellingprice', 'money', array(
                'label'         => 'Instant Selling Price',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Instant Selling Price')
            ))
            ->add('entityCondition', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('n' => 'New', 'u' => 'Used'),
                'label'         => 'Condition',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Condition')
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Entities',
            'validation_groups' => array('entity'),
        ));
    }

}
```

My Entities Class:

```
/**
 * Entities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_users1", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_countries1_idx", columns={"region_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_categories1_idx", columns={"category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entities
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $entityId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityDescription;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_starttime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityStarttime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_endtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityEndtime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_instantsellingprice", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityInstantsellingprice;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_shippingprice", type="decimal", precision=6, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityShippingprice;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_condition", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityCondition;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_views", type="bigint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityViews;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="region_id")
     * })
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Get entityId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEntityId()
    {
        return $this->entityId;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityTitle
     *
     * @param string $entityTitle
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityTitle($entityTitle)
    {
        $this->entityTitle = $entityTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityTitle()
    {
        return $this->entityTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityDescription
     *
     * @param string $entityDescription
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityDescription($entityDescription)
    {
        $this->entityDescription = $entityDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityDescription()
    {
        return $this->entityDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityStarttime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityStarttime
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityStarttime($entityStarttime)
    {
        $this->entityStarttime = $entityStarttime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityStarttime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityStarttime()
    {
        return $this->entityStarttime;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityEndtime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityEndtime
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityEndtime($entityEndtime)
    {
        $this->entityEndtime = $entityEndtime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityEndtime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityEndtime()
    {
        return $this->entityEndtime;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityInstantsellingprice
     *
     * @param string $entityInstantsellingprice
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityInstantsellingprice($entityInstantsellingprice)
    {
        $this->entityInstantsellingprice = $entityInstantsellingprice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityInstantsellingprice
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityInstantsellingprice()
    {
        return $this->entityInstantsellingprice;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityShippingprice
     *
     * @param string $entityShippingprice
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityShippingprice($entityShippingprice)
    {
        $this->entityShippingprice = $entityShippingprice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityShippingprice
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityShippingprice()
    {
        return $this->entityShippingprice;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityCondition
     *
     * @param string $entityCondition
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityCondition($entityCondition)
    {
        $this->entityCondition = $entityCondition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityCondition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityCondition()
    {
        return $this->entityCondition;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityViews
     *
     * @param integer $entityViews
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityViews($entityViews)
    {
        $this->entityViews = $entityViews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityViews
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEntityViews()
    {
        return $this->entityViews;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityCreated
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityCreated($entityCreated)
    {
        $this->entityCreated = $entityCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityCreated()
    {
        return $this->entityCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityModified
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityModified($entityModified)
    {
        $this->entityModified = $entityModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityModified()
    {
        return $this->entityModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityDeleted
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityDeleted($entityDeleted)
    {
        $this->entityDeleted = $entityDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityDeleted()
    {
        return $this->entityDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setUser(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set region
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions $region
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setRegion(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions $region = null)
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions 
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories $category
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setCategory(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
/**
 * Entities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_users1", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_countries1_idx", columns={"region_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_entities_categories1_idx", columns={"category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entities
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $entityId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityDescription;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_starttime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityStarttime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_endtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityEndtime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_instantsellingprice", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityInstantsellingprice;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_shippingprice", type="decimal", precision=6, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityShippingprice;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_condition", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityCondition;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_views", type="bigint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityViews;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $entityCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="region_id")
     * })
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Get entityId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEntityId()
    {
        return $this->entityId;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityTitle
     *
     * @param string $entityTitle
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityTitle($entityTitle)
    {
        $this->entityTitle = $entityTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityTitle()
    {
        return $this->entityTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityDescription
     *
     * @param string $entityDescription
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityDescription($entityDescription)
    {
        $this->entityDescription = $entityDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityDescription()
    {
        return $this->entityDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityStarttime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityStarttime
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityStarttime($entityStarttime)
    {
        $this->entityStarttime = $entityStarttime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityStarttime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityStarttime()
    {
        return $this->entityStarttime;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityEndtime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityEndtime
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityEndtime($entityEndtime)
    {
        $this->entityEndtime = $entityEndtime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityEndtime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityEndtime()
    {
        return $this->entityEndtime;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityInstantsellingprice
     *
     * @param string $entityInstantsellingprice
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityInstantsellingprice($entityInstantsellingprice)
    {
        $this->entityInstantsellingprice = $entityInstantsellingprice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityInstantsellingprice
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityInstantsellingprice()
    {
        return $this->entityInstantsellingprice;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityShippingprice
     *
     * @param string $entityShippingprice
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityShippingprice($entityShippingprice)
    {
        $this->entityShippingprice = $entityShippingprice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityShippingprice
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityShippingprice()
    {
        return $this->entityShippingprice;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityCondition
     *
     * @param string $entityCondition
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityCondition($entityCondition)
    {
        $this->entityCondition = $entityCondition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityCondition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEntityCondition()
    {
        return $this->entityCondition;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityViews
     *
     * @param integer $entityViews
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityViews($entityViews)
    {
        $this->entityViews = $entityViews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityViews
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEntityViews()
    {
        return $this->entityViews;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityCreated
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityCreated($entityCreated)
    {
        $this->entityCreated = $entityCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityCreated()
    {
        return $this->entityCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityModified
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityModified($entityModified)
    {
        $this->entityModified = $entityModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityModified()
    {
        return $this->entityModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $entityDeleted
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setEntityDeleted($entityDeleted)
    {
        $this->entityDeleted = $entityDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entityDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEntityDeleted()
    {
        return $this->entityDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setUser(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set region
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions $region
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setRegion(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions $region = null)
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Regions 
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories $category
     * @return Entities
     */
    public function setCategory(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Categories 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

I also have a Table Media with:

- medium_id
- entity_id
- medium_url
- medium_type

In my view I now have:

```
    <form novalidate="novalidate" id="form-Entity" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Entity Page</legend>
        <dl>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityTitle, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.entityTitle) }}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityDescription, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {# form_errors (form.password) #}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityStarttime, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control datepicker'} }) }}
                {# form_errors (form.password) #}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityEndtime, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control datepicker'} }) }}
                {# form_errors (form.password) #}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityInstantsellingprice, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {# form_errors (form.password) #}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.entityCondition, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {# form_errors (form.password) #}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                {{ form_row (form.category.categoryName, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors (form.category.categoryName) }}
            </dd>
            <dd class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="fileupload" type="file" name="entity[files]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
    {{ form_rest(form)}}
    <p><input class="btn btn-primary" name="" type="submit" value="Create Entity!"></p>
</form>
```

As you can see I manually added `<input class="form-control" id="fileupload" type="file" name="entity[files]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />` to my form because I can't use media in my formtype (not in entites class).

The uploading works fine, but when I check $_POST in the controller the files are not included. How can I include this?

**UPDATE:**
The var_dump from $_POST shows me this:

```
array (size=1)
'entity' => 
   array (size=8)
     'entityTitle' => string 'sdqqsdsqd' (length=9)
     'entityDescription' => string 'sqdssqd' (length=7)
     'entityStarttime' => string '2014/01/22 00:00' (length=16)
     'entityEndtime' => string '2014/01/18 00:00' (length=16)
     'entityInstantsellingprice' => string '12' (length=2)
     'entityCondition' => string 'n' (length=1)
     'category' => 
       array (size=1)
         'categoryName' => string '1' (length=1)
     '_token' => string 'oiflDN-Y0QPQrRzW9IIM8lB37LDbUQBvdR4LitsF2Ks' (length=43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" id="form-Entity" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get anything from the files in my $_POST. (Updated begin post with dump $_POST)

Comment: Don't use $_POST. First, define request and then use it like; $request->files->get("your_file");

Comment: Thanks, now I get the names of the files. But the jquery file upload always saves different names of the original file. Do you know how I can set that he uses the original name?

Comment: Which uploader? You asked for post file request.

Comment: I dont know. Check for documentation maybe?